# filtering filnames in dir through combining arraylist-elements

Tags: java

I'm searching through a directory for different filenames and extensions with `textFile.getName().endsWith();`.

In `endsWith()` i want to be able to combine different array-elements of a string-array that looks like this i.e:

`String[] fileName = {"_clause", "_regulator"};
 String[] fileType = {".txt", ".doc"};`

my condition:

`if(textFiles.isFile() && textFiles.getName().endsWith(fileName[0]+fileType[1])) {`

You can see that i'm combining index 0 and 1 in this case.

But what if i wanted to also include 1 and 1 here, i can't just do `||`.

like: <s>`.endsWith(fileName[0]+fileType[1] || fileName[1]+fileType[1])) {`</s>

How would I go about solving this?

Thanks.

Solution by Joeri Hendrickx would look like this:

```
Pattern filenamePattern = Pattern.compile("(_clause)|(_regulator)\\.(txt)|(doc)$");

if(textFiles.isFile() && filenamePattern.matcher(textFiles.getName()).find()) {
```

Comment: What about using a method with two nested for loops in it? I know, not the prettiest and fastest solution, but you might give it a shot.

Comment: By the way, the `filenamePattern` should be defined at class level as a `private static final` var. Not recreated every time through this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably be easiest to solve with a regex.

So you'd get

```
filenamePattern = Pattern.compile("(_clause|_regulator)\\.(doc|txt)$");
return filenamePattern.matcher(textFile.getName()).find()
```

Comment: This is not the same as `endsWith`. It's more like `contains`.

Comment: Although this solution doesn't use `endsWith` it solves the problem. +1

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I added the anchor to be like an endswith. thanks!

Comment: @Joel No, it will also match `_clause.txt.gz` or `_clause.docx`. (The edited version fixes it.)

Comment: @Joel if this answers your question appropriately, you can accept it by clicking the check on the left